# is it possible to have a table embedded in message of dash dcc.confirmdialog?

Tags: python, plotly-dash, confirm-dialog

Trying to see if I can enhance the confirmdialog pop up message window by passing not only string but maybe a dash table with a few records and option to collapse it for user. Is that possible?

https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/confirmdialog

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to render Dash or HTML components in a dcc.ConfirmDialog. Only a string can be displayed within the ConfirmDialog using the `message` property, no `children` property exists to render other dash components.

However, this dash component is an instance of a browser's native confirm Modal. So you could use the dash-bootstrap-components [`Modal`](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/modal/) component, which could potentially take in Dash-tables.